# Does storage access framework work on Xiaomi devices?

Tags: android

I have an app that lets users open files via the storage access framework, edit them, and then overwrite the previously open file. In short this is the essential code:

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> mGetContent;
private Uri OpenFileUri;

public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
                    try (InputStream in = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri))
                    {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                        String text = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
                        binding.editBox.setText(text);

                        OpenFileUri = uri;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

    binding.buttonOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mGetContent.launch(new String[] {"text/*"});
        }
    });

    binding.buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (OpenFileUri == null)
                return;

            try (OutputStream mOutputStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(OpenFileUri, "wt")) {
                try (PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(mOutputStream)) {
                    String t = binding.editBox.getText().toString();
                    p.println(t);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Full code is available here: https://github.com/pekspro/CorruptFileDemo (created for a different purpose)

The app does work fine for most of my users, but one is using Xiaomi 11T Pro with Android 11. A device I do not have access to :-(. Other devices with Anroid 11 works fine. This user could open a file, but an exception is thrown when the file is saved (not sure what, do not have any logs). My real app also trying to call [takePersistableUriPermission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#takePersistableUriPermission(android.net.Uri,%20int)), but this also throws an `java.lang.SecurityException` on this device.

When I run the app and open a file, the URI is:

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/…
```

But for this user, it instead begins with:

```
content://com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/external_files/Documents/…
```

This makes me suspect that [Mi File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer) is used as a document selector on Xaomi devices.

If I open a file directly in [Mi File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer) I see that is only has read only permissions.

Is this behavior expected for (some) Xiaomi devices? For testing purposes, can some force my app to use [Mi File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer) as document selector?

Comment: You should directly in onActivityResult take persistable uri permission. Are you checking if you can take both read and write permission? As then both flags should be set by the provider. Please report.

Comment: DId you test other Android 11 devices?

Comment: `but an exception is thrown when the file is saved. ` Which exception? You did not post a log.

Comment: Did you install that app yourself? And did you see that provider? And did it go wrong on your Android device where you installed that app?

Comment: `can some force my app to use this app as document selector?` Well if the app is not a document provider then that will not go. What you could do however is use that app to go to a file and then let the user read and edit the file with your app. You can do all on your own Android device.

Comment: Good points @blackapps, I have updated the question.

Comment: I installed Mi File Manager on an Android 11 device. It does not react on ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT but i could browse to a file with it and let it open in my editor app. Only a read permission was given so no wonder edited content could not be saved. It's the provider you mentioned.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: No, @ALKINÇAKIRALAR, I never found a proper solution. Currently I’m checking if the file is read only, and if that is the case a show a warning to the user. I have seen [at least on application]( https://apkpure.com/split-apks-installer-sai/com.aefyr.sai) that has added an internal file browser, I guess that is because of Xiamoi.

Answer (score 0):

> > Does storage access framework work on Xaomi devices?

Yes all you posted works.

Only a provider gives no write access to a file choosen by user.

(But maybe there is a setting that would give it ?? ...)