# open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) on Android 12, Xiaomi 11 Ultra device

Tags: java, android, kotlin, pdf-viewer, xiaomi

When one of users try to open a downloaded pdf file having this error.

I am using DownloadManager to download the pdf file from url.
Also I am using 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1' library as a pdf viewer.

It works without a problem with all devices except Xiaomi Mi 11 Ultra. In that model device it gives the "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)" error. Sample code below:

```
val fileName = "${File.separator}${"Presentation_Report"}${System.currentTimeMillis()}.pdf"

        fileHelper.downloadFile(url, fileName) { response, msg ->

            runOnUiThread {

                onLoadingChange(false)

                if (response.status && response.data != null) {

                    this.file = response.data

                    binding.pdfView.fromFile(response.data)
                        .onError {

                            FirebaseAnalyticsHelper.sendReportError(
                                this,
                                "Preview Activity pdf load error $url $fileName \n PDF VIEWER ERR : ${it.message ?: ""}"
                            )

                            finish()

                            fileHelper.viewFileOnError(file)

                        }
                        .load()

                } else {

                    showErrorAlert(AlertViewType.Warning, msg) { finish() }

                }

            }

        }
```

Variable response.data is the File we successfully downloaded.

In the binding.pdfView.fromFile(response.data).onError, it throws the error I described above.

I am using runtime permissions and also user has enabled all the permission in his phone.

The problem only occurs in the Xiaomi Mi 11 Ultra.

These are my download file function and broadcast receiver to receive response after download.

```
fun downloadFile(
        url: String,
        fileName: String,
        completion: (DataResponse<File>, String) -> Unit
    ) {

        try {

            this.currentUrl = url

            this.currentFileName = fileName

            this.onDownload = completion

            val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager

            val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))

            request.setTitle(fileName)

            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(
                context,
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                fileName
            )

            downloadManager.enqueue(request)

            context.registerReceiver(
                downloadReceiver,
                IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)
            )

        } catch (e: NullPointerException) {

            this.logReport("NullPointerException", e.message)

            completion(getErrorResponseData(), R.string.shared_unexpected_error.localized())

        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {

            this.logReport("IllegalArgumentException", e.message)

            completion(getErrorResponseData(), R.string.shared_unexpected_error.localized())

        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {

            this.logReport("IllegalStateException", e.message)

            completion(getErrorResponseData(), R.string.shared_unexpected_error.localized())

        } catch (e: SecurityException) {

            this.logReport("SecurityException", e.message)

            completion(getErrorResponseData(), R.string.shared_unexpected_error.localized())

        } catch (e: Throwable) {

            this.logReport("Throwable", e.message)

            completion(getErrorResponseData(), R.string.shared_unexpected_error.localized())

        }

    }

private val downloadReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {

            val downloadDirectory = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS ?: ""

            val fileLocation =
                this@FileHelper.context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)?.path
                    ?: ""

            if (downloadDirectory.isEmpty()) {
                context?.let {
                    FirebaseAnalyticsHelper.sendReportError(
                        it,
                        "Download Directory Is Empty \n" +
                                "Url : ${this@FileHelper.currentUrl}"
                    )
                }
            }

            if (fileLocation.isEmpty()) {
                context?.let {
                    FirebaseAnalyticsHelper.sendReportError(
                        it,
                        "File Location Is Empty \n" +
                                "Url : ${this@FileHelper.currentUrl}"
                    )
                }
            }

            val file =
                File("${this@FileHelper.context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)}${this@FileHelper.currentFileName}")

            context?.let { FirebaseAnalyticsHelper.logToMixPanel(it, file.toString()) }

            if (file.exists()) {

                this@FileHelper.onDownload?.let {
                    it(getSuccessResponseData(file), "")
                }

            } else {

                val writeExternalStoragePermission =
                    PermissionHelper(this@FileHelper.fragmentActivity).checkPermission(
                        PermissionType.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    )
                val readExternalStoragePermission =
                    PermissionHelper(this@FileHelper.fragmentActivity).checkPermission(
                        PermissionType.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    )

                context?.let {
                    FirebaseAnalyticsHelper.sendReportError(
                        it,
                        "File Not Exists \n" +
                                "File Path : ${file.path} \n" +
                                "File Absolute Path : ${file.absolutePath} \n " +
                                "Url : ${this@FileHelper.currentUrl} \n " +
                                "writeExternalStoragePermission: $writeExternalStoragePermission \n " +
                                "readExternalStoragePermission: $readExternalStoragePermission"
                    )
                }

                this@FileHelper.onDownload?.let {
                    it(
                        getErrorResponseData(),
                        R.string.listing_detail_report_result_page_error_file_not_found.localized()
                    )
                }

            }

            this@FileHelper.context.unregisterReceiver(this)

        }

    }
```

These are my declared uses permissions in the manifest which are:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

How can I solve this issue.

With a little digging, I found something about Mi File Manager. However, I do not know that if this is related with my issue
[The question about Mi File Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71275400/does-storage-access-framework-work-on-xaomi-devices)

Comment: `this.file = response.data` Please tell the value of response.data.

Comment: @blackapps response.data is the file we successfully downloaded which binding.pdfView.fromFile function requires File parameter.

Comment: String name = "stack";  The value of variable name is 'stack'; Now reread my comment, i asked for the value of response.data.